# How do I make an old profile picture on Facebook my picture again AND make it be at the beginning of the list?

Tags: facebook, profile-picture, facebook-profile

I recently went through my profile pictures and deleted old, embarrassing ones. I then realized I had hardly any profile pictures left so, all at once, I added a bunch of more recent pictures of myself as profile pictures and changed the dates in the description. After I did this I had more pictures of myself as my profile picture so, I changed my profile picture back to the one it was before. (I went to the picture, went to options, make profile picture.) However, now all the pictures I had just made my profile pictures (mentioned above) come before my profile picture because my current profile picture is one from an earlier date and Facebook displays it from the old date. I want my current profile picture to be the 1st picture in the list but because it was an older picture, when I click on it, it shows that is the 10th in the list. I want it to be displayed as the 1st so when people look through my pictures, they will see the newer ones of me first rather than the older ones (but I don't want to upload the picture again because I want the likes and comments on it still). If this makes any sense, can anyone please help me?